# Does C has any built in functions?

Tags: c

There are around 50 built in functions in Python. The `printf` and `scanf` functions of C is comes under `stdio.h` library.

Are there any functions in C that are the part of language itself?

Comment: The C standard library is part of the language, yes. The ISO 9899 standard is not available for free, but drafts are freely available, see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/projects

Comment: How do you define a "built-in function"? You're free to declare `printf` and `scanf` yourself if you don't want to include `stdio.h` for some reason. In C89 you don't even need to declare them.

Comment: There are compiler intrinsics, which often correspond one to one with cpu instructions, but those are compiler and cpu specific, and not standardized

Comment: I don't know if something like `sizeof()` counts as a function (some sources say it's a function, and some say it's an operator).

Comment: Does `defined` on preprocessor stage, or `sizeof` and `_Alignof` count? maybe `_Generic`? These are "expressions", it really depends no how you define a "builtin function".

Comment: @Brendan According to standard `sizeof` and like are not functions. `sizeof`, `_Alignof` and `_Pragma` are operators, and `_Static_assert` is declaration.

Comment: @user694733: I'd expect that a Python programmer would say `sizeof()` is a function; I just don't know for sure that it counts as a function to the original asker. For the C standard, they could pick any random sequence of characters and define it to mean whatever they like and it makes no difference to anything outside the spec. E.g. if someone says "My wife has to go to a work function for cancer research" it'd be silly to say "Oh, that's not a function according to the C spec".

Answer (score 4):

C has a few keywords, but no built-in functions. Every function you use comes from some other library. It is possible to compile a program even without the standard library using `-nostdlib` flag (for gcc).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "part of the language". There are specifications that define what the C standard library should offer, so to that extent `printf()`, etc., are "part of the language".

However, a C compiler won't generate the code that implements these functions -- they are expected to be provided in a library of some kind. Most C compilers will know where/what the library is, and will be configured to link it automatically. You can almost certainly tell the compiler/linker not to do this, if you don't want to use the standard library. There are sometimes good reasons to.

Although there is a specification for a standard library, the language syntax itself has little-to-no coupling to the library. In Java, for example, if you add a `String` and an object, the compiler will generate code to call the object's `toString()` method. This method has to exist, because the Java language and the Java runtime library are closely related.

There's no real equivalent to this process in C -- C compilers can generate code in complete ignorance of what functions might be available. Those functions do need to be made available before runtime, but that's really the job of the linker, rather than the compiler.

However, `gcc` at least *does* have a notion of "built-in" functions. For example, if I try to compile this:

```
void printf (void)
  {
  }
```

I get a warning:

```
test.c:1:6: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 
‘printf’; expected ‘int(const char *, ...)’ [-Wbuiltin-
 declaration-mismatch]
```

even if I use the `-nostdlib` switch. Even with no standard library, `gcc` still thinks of `printf()` as being "built-in" even though it doesn't generate code for it.

I guess that notion of a "built-in function" isn't entirely clear-cut.

Comment: “However, a C compiler won't generate the code that implements these functions” is not true. Compilers do generate such code. `memcpy` and `sqrt` are commonly replaced by inline code, for example.

Comment: OK, fair point. I concede that  a compiler might generate code for functions that are capable of being inlined. Presumably this is a relatively small subset of all the functions that exist.

Answer (score 1):

All C standard library functions are built into the language—they are part of the C language as defined by the C standard. C implementations (notably compilers) may implement these functions either as built-in functions implemented by the compiler or as object modules linked in by the linker. The C standard largely separates the rules that says how C programs must behave from rules about how C programs must be implemented.

In the sense of how a C program must behave, there is no difference between a built-in function or a linked-in function: The function behaves the same, and there is no way to describe an observable difference between the two implementations.

Compilers generally use a mix of built-in implementations and linked-in implementations. For example, in `void foo(uint32_t u) { float f; memcpy(&f, &u, sizeof f); … }`, a compiler may implement the `memcpy` by generating an instruction to move data from an integer register to a floating-point register and not by calling any external `memcpy` routine. For other `memcpy` calls, it might generate simple instructions to move bytes and again not call an external routine. For `sqrt`, it might generate a square-root instruction if the target machine has an appropriate one.

More complicated functions are more often implemented by calling external functions that are linked into the program after compilation. Even with many of these, the compiler may recognize special cases and provide calls to alternative functions (`printf("Hello, world.\n")` may be implemented as if it were `puts("Hello, world.")`, instructions that perform the function without a call (`pow(x, 2)` may be implemented as a multiplication of `x` by itself), or results may be computed at compile time, by code built into the compiler (`sin(.3)` might be evaluated at at compile time).

Comment: While  don't disagree with any of this, there remains a radical difference between the way that, say, `printf()` is provided to a C programmer, and `System.out.println()` to a Java programmer. I've worked in many environments where the C implementation did not have a `printf()` or even a `malloc()`; but it's inconceivable that a Java JVM would not have `System.out`. That a C compiler can be divorced from a particular standard library is highly significant in embedded systems.